# How set an authenticated user in Parse tests?

Tags: parse-platform

I've some tests configured for Parse, but I don't know how to set the authenticated user in `Parse.Cloud.run`:

```
it('set user authenticated', function(done) {
  var user = new Parse.User({username: 'example2', password: 'example'});
  user.save();
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(function() {
    return Parse.Cloud.run('thread', { user: { id: user.id } });
  })
});
```

So in the cloud function I've `request.user.id` and it throws `Undefined request.user`

More info: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in how you are using promises in your code above:

```
user.save();
Promise.resolve()
   .then(function() {
     return Parse.Cloud.run('thread', { user: { id: user.id } });
   })
```

You don't want to use `Promise.resolve().then()`.  You would want `user.save().then()`

Below are two sets of working unit test that I think exercises what you want.

This first one passes the user id as a parameter:

```
describe('pass parameters to cloud code', () => {
  // set up the cloud code function
  beforeEach(() => {
    Parse.Cloud.define('thread', (request, response) => {
      // just return the user id that passed in so we can test it.
      response.success(request.params.user.id);
    });
  });

  it('should pass parameters', (done) => {
    const user = new Parse.User({ 
      username: 'example2',
      password: 'example' 
    });

    user.save()
      .then(() => Parse.Cloud.run('thread', { user: { id: user.id } }))
      .then((result) => expect(result).toBe(user.id))
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```

And this second set of tests shows how an authenticated user is passed to cloud code.

```
describe('user in cloud code unit test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Parse.Cloud.define('thread', (request, response) => {
      const result = request.user
        ? request.user
        : 'no user set';
      response.success(result);
    });
  });

  it('should not have a user', (done) => {
    Parse.Cloud.run('thread')
      .then(result => expect(result).toBe('no user set'))
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should get the logged in user', (done) => {
    Parse.User.signUp('Alice', 'Password', { name: 'value' })
      // note that we don't have to pass the logged in user
      // if there is a logged in user, it'll be in request.user           
      .then(() => Parse.Cloud.run('thread'))
      .then(userAsResult => expect(userAsResult.get('username', 'Alice')))
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to send it in the test, not check if it is the user is the current one

Comment: ok, answer edited with an actual test using the code idiom I pointed out.

Comment: Awesome work! but this overrides the real function, and I can't test the real one. Also the if you send `{ user: { id: user.id } }`, it'll be read in the cloud function in `request.params.user.id`, not in `request.user`

Comment: Pull the code you want to test into a function and then export it.  That way, in your test, your can `Parse.Cloud.define('toTest', exportedFunction);`  and you can still `Parse.Cloud.define('blah', exportedFunction)` in the file where the `exportedFunction` is defined.

Comment: That could work if I test the function as separated and not the cloud one, so I've to pass the user as param of the function. It isn't the answer that I expect, but it works, so I'll mark it as correct, thanks!